# macOS does not browse folder on SMB share (folder displayed as light-blue folder)

Tags: network, sharing, smb

macOS does not browse a folder on SMB share. The folder displayed as light blue folder. The folder was copied onto this share exactly from the same Mac with the same user. Permissions are 100% okay on the server.

I can happily create a new folder without problems next to it (Co...shows the folder that does not work):

[image]

Here is the output when I switch to the share in Terminal and use `ls -@ -la`:

```
Mac:share user$ ls -@ -a -l
total 153
drwx------  1 user      staff  16384 Dec 22 20:09 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 root      wheel    224 Dec 22 20:08 ..
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user      staff  10244 Dec 22 20:09 .DS_Store
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxrwxrwx  1 user      staff  16384 Dec 13 23:58 .zfs
drwxr-xr-x@ 1 user      staff  16384 Dec 22 12:55 Co......
    com.apple.finder.copy.source.inode#N        8 
    com.apple.finder.copy.source.volumeuuid#N     36 
drwxr-xr-x  1 user      staff  16384 Dec 22 20:08 test
```

In the samba logs I can see that the Mac accesses all files but they still don't show up.

Also, the directory **can be traversed and written to without any issues in Terminal**!

Other shares on the same server work well.

Comment: Perhaps a screen cap showing that and another folder for comparison. Also a directory listing showing all attributes on that and one working folder. We will need more info to help you, please edit your question and the requested info.

Comment: I am happy to but please tell me which more info would be required and how I could do a directory listing for debug. What does it mean when a folder is "light blue"? (I am well versed in Linux and Windows but not much clue in MacOS)

Comment: Just as I suggested, a picture of the screen showing the problematic folder and one that works next to each other. Also https://ss64.com/osx/ls.html will help you in getting a long directory listing with extended attributes. Paste the results into your original question and add the screen capture of the two (at least) folders to your original question.

Comment: How was the folder copied? Was it copied from Mac to Mac by a Finder drag, or was the copy executed on the SMB server? Execute the **Get Info** command (Command-I) on each selected folder to show its details, then use the disclosure triangle to show the **Sharing & Permissions** sheet at the bottom to see users' ownership, permissions & privileges on the folder. If the bad folder has different settings than the good one, you need to investigate how to make the settings identical. This may need to be done on the server, or the copy may need to be redone somehow. Perhaps an SMB maven help.

Comment: @SteveChambers: Added screenshot and `ls -@ -la` output

Comment: @IconDaemon: Yes, it was copied from the very same Mac using finder to drop the folder onto the share. Probably something was interrupted (10GB or 50GB were copied). Thanks for the **Get Info** suggestions. Both good and bad folder show identical permissions (Read & Write for user (Me), Read only for staff, Read only for everyone)

Comment: Now comes the crazy thing: In the terminal I can traverse the whole directory tree without issues (e.g. `find .` does not return any error). I can also create new files and folders inside! Can this be a Finder issue? Rebooting the Mac did not help.

Comment: If you log in as a different user on your Mac directly after reboot (create one first if required), does it work?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, something was wrong with the file creation date. Which is weird because everything on the Linux side was *definitely* fine (`stat`)!

```
SetFile -d '12/21/2020 01:01:01' Co.....
```

fixed the issue, as described in [Grayed out folder won't open in finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216230/grayed-out-folder-wont-open-in-finder).

Answer (score 0):

To restore visibility:

1. Remove following extended attributes from folder:

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.finder.copy.source.inode#N <Foldername>
sudo xattr -d com.apple.finder.copy.source.volumeuuid#N <Foldername>
```

2. Delete .DS_Store file **inside problem folder**

```
cd <Foldername>
rm .DS_Store
```