# How to remove the "resumable copy" flag of a folder?

Tags: macos, finder, monterey

Since Monterey it is possible to finish copying at a later point of time.

I want to remove this flag because I have already transmitted it manually with rsync.
I checked what attributes the folder set, but removing those didn't help.

Does anyone know how to reset Finder's view?

I tried following with no luck:

```
$ xattr my_folder
com.apple.finder.copy.checkpoint#N
com.apple.finder.copy.source.inode#N
com.apple.finder.copy.source.volumeuuid#N
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemResumableCopy

$ xattr -rc my_folder
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I was banging my head trying to find any articles about this as I'd aborted a large copy job... I saw there were extended attributes and was able to clear them but did not make the "connection" to adjust the date/time of the file(s). I guess that tweaks the archive bit(s) or something so APFS sheds the "resume copy" attribute or something? NICE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Came across the same problem. After cleaning the `kMDItemResumableCopy` metadata with `xattr -rc`, the folder became greyed out and couldn't be opened with Finder (Terminal was still fine).

I followed the steps [mentioned here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/293700/446834) and set the folder's creation date manually which fixed the problem.

```bsh
$ xattr -rc my_folder

$ SetFile -d '12/31/1999 23:59:59' my_folder
```

Comment: This worked for me on Monterey v12.7.3   Thank you very much.  The grayed out folder with 80gB of stuck "resumeable copy data became a normal Finder folder by executing the above two Terminal commands and using the same date as the example the now normal folder shows my local date.   Application Beyond Compare was also able to access the folder and let me finish the copy, but it was not able to convert the grayed out folder into a normal Finder accessible folder.   Why on earth are APPLE "features" so wrong headed ?

Answer (score 1):

When you have originally started a with a resumable copy via finder on MacOS and then realise you'd prefer a faster rsync method, you can be left with the resumable copy ghost folder, making the rsync'd data inaccessible from finder.

Just use this function either in a script or define at the commandline to resolve the issue:

```
function fixFolder {
  file=$1
  mod_date=$(stat -f "%Sm" "$file")
  xattr -drs com.apple.metadata:kMDItemResumableCopy $file
  SetFile -d "$mod_date" "$file"
}
```

then just do:

`$ fixFolder myBrokenFolder`

This will only update the create date to make it accessible and remove the resumable copy flag. Both steps are needed.